$\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathrm{Out}(F_n)/\langle\langle \epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$
In a paper I found the following result:
$$\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathrm{Out}(F_n)/\langle\langle \epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$$
However, they got the result as a corollary of a pretty strong result. I was wondering if there is a direct proof for this fact. Here $\epsilon_i$ is the automorphism of $F_n$ that inverts the $i$-th generator and leaves the rest fixed.
Thanks for your help.
Edit: The natural approach I was thinking is to consider the map given by the abelianization and compose it with the reduction mod $2$:
$$\varphi:\mathrm{Out}(F_n)\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$$
This is trivially an epimorphism and I proving that $\ker(\varphi)=\langle\langle \epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$ will solve the problem. $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ is generated by $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n,\lambda_{i,j}$ with $i,j=1,\dots,n$ and $i\neq j$. ($\lambda_{i,j}(v_i)=v_iv_j$ and $\lambda_{i,j}(v_k)=v_k$ if $k\neq i$, where $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are the generators of $F_n$). But there are elements such as $\lambda_{i,j}^2$ that lie in $\ker(\varphi)$ and I cannot prove that they lie in $\langle\langle \epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$.

What was the paper where you found the result?

Here is a strategy that is successful for $n = 2$. Let $IA(F_n)$ be the group of Bachmuth automorphisms of $F_n$ (see Lyndon-Schupp, Sec. I.4). Let $Inn(F_n)$ be the group of the inner automorphisms of $F_n$. Then we know that $Aut(F_n)/IA(F_n) \simeq GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (Proposition 4.4) and it is not difficult to show that $Aut(F_n)/\langle\langle IA(F_n),\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n\rangle\rangle \simeq GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z})$.

... It remains to check that $\langle\langle IA(F_n),\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n\rangle\rangle \subseteq \langle\langle Inn(F_n),\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$. If $n = 2$, we have $IA(F_n) = Inn(F_n)$ (Proposition 4.5), so we are done. If $n \ge 2$, we know that $IA(F_n) = \langle\langle \alpha_{112} \rangle\rangle$ and $\alpha_{112}^2 \in \langle\langle Inn(F_n),\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$ (see remarks following Corollary 4.15).

@LSpice In the paper I found the result they claimed that it was an imediate corollary of a result from ''Finite Factor Groups of the Unimodular Group'' by Mennike. However, I don't really undestand why this is a corollary from that paper.

@LucGuyot If we assume that $n\geq 3$ then $IA(F_n)$ is in general much bigger than $\mathrm{Inn}(F_n)$, since the first group contains all partial conjugations and some transvections and the second contains just the inner automorphisms, which is a particular case of conjugations. So we should check that any partial conjugations lies in $\langle\langle\mathrm{Inn}(F_n),\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n\rangle\rangle$, but it doesn't seem true...

The statement "$\langle \langle \alpha_{112} \rangle \rangle \in \langle \langle \operatorname{Inn}(F_n), \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \rangle \rangle$" is equivalent to the truth of the theorem you mentioned in your question. The fact that $\langle \langle \alpha_{112}^2 \rangle \rangle \in \langle \langle \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \rangle \rangle $ shows that we are "close" to it.

Side remark: In order to show that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})/ \langle \langle \overline{\epsilon_1}, \dots, \overline{\epsilon_n} \rangle \rangle \simeq \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z})$, where $\overline{\epsilon}_i$ is the image of $\epsilon_i$ in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, we only need to know that $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}, 2 \mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z}, 2 \mathbb{Z})$, which is certainly weaker than the Congruence Subgroup Theorem for $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ that is completed in Mennick's paper.

@LSpice: I'm not sure why the OP is so reluctant to mention the paper they have been looking at. A plausible guess is Kielak's https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1624 -- see Proposition 2.8 therein. The question can now be restated as: "1. How does the stated fact follow from Mennicke's proof of the congruence subgroup property (CSP)? 2. Is there a proof that avoids the CSP?" Both seem like reasonable questions. It should be possible to deduce it from Gersten's presentation (Proposition 2.5 in Kielak's paper). At the very least, Mennicke's main result doesn't apply when $n=2$.

It is easy to see from Gersten's presentation that $\lambda_{ij}^2=1$. Indeed, by (vii) (in Proposition 2.5 of Kielak's paper), setting $\epsilon_i=1$ forces $\rho_{ij}=\lambda_{ji}^{-1}$, and also $\rho_{ij}^2=1$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{Out}{Out} \DeclareMathOperator{Aut}{Aut} \DeclareMathOperator{IA}{IA}$
The key thing that is missing is that the Torelli subgroup of $\Out(F_n)$ is contained in the normal closure of these elements.  This is in fact true, and is a very special case of a theorem will appear in my student Jiayi Shen's thesis.  More generally, her thesis will prove that in most cases, the $\Out(F_n)$-normal closure of a finite subgroup of $\Out(F_n)$ is what you would guess to be (there are a few cases, and more generally she has to assume that $n \geq 3$ and can't handle everything that happens at the prime $2$, though for the special case asked here she has no issues). Since it is not yet posted to the arXiv, I will give the argument here specialized to this particularly easy case.
Instead of $\Out(F_n)$, I will prove it for $\Aut(F_n)$ (which is enough).  Let $\IA_n$ be the Torelli subgroup of $\Aut(F_n)$.  Let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be the standard basis of $F_n$.  For distinct $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, let $C_{ij} \in \IA_n$ be the element that conjugates $x_i$ by $x_j$.  A classical theorem of Nielsen says that the $\Aut(F_n)$-normal closure of $C_{12}$ is $\IA_n$, so it is enough to prove that $C_{12}$ is in the indicated subgroup.
One element of the subgroup in question is the map $f\colon F_n \rightarrow F_n$ that inverts $x_1$ and $x_2$ and fixes all the other $x_i$.  Let $L_{ij} \in \Aut(F_n)$ be the Nielsen transformation that multiplies $x_i$ on the left by $x_j$.  The subgroup in question then contains
$$(L_{12} f L_{12}^{-1}) f^{-1},$$
which equals $C_{12}$ by the following calculation:

First,

$$L_{12} f L_{12}^{-1} f^{-1}(x_1) = L_{12} f L_{12}^{-1}(x_1^{-1}) = L_{12} f (x_1^{-1} x_2) = L_{12}(x_1 x_2^{-1}) = x_2 x_1 x_2^{-1}.$$

Second, for $i \geq 2$ for an appropriate choice of sign depending on whether $i=2$ or $i \geq 3$ we have

$$L_{12} f L_{12}^{-1} f^{-1}(x_i) = L_{12} f L_{12}^{-1}(x_i^{\pm 1}) = L_{12} f(x_i^{\pm 1}) = L_{12}(x_i) = x_i.$$

Edit. Assertion $(ii)$ of the Claim below is now given by the commutator computation of Andy Putman's answer (see Remark 2 below for notational match). This provides us with a proof of OP's isomorphism.

The isomorphism result mentioned in OP's question, that is [3, Proposition 2.8], holds true if $n = 2$. The general case can be reduced to the following statement:

Claim. Let $n \ge 2$. Let $F_n$ be the free group with basis $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$. Let $\operatorname{Inn}(F_n)$ the group of inner automorphisms of $F_n$. Let $\epsilon_i, \rho_{ij}$ and $\lambda_{ij}$ be defined as in [3] (see re-definitions below).
Then the following are equivalent:

$(i)$ The quotient group $Q:=\operatorname{Out}(F_n)/ \langle \langle \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \rangle\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.
$(ii)$ The image of $\alpha_{112} := \rho_{12} \lambda_{12}^{-1}$ is trivial in $Q$, i.e., we have  $$\alpha_{112} \in \langle \langle \operatorname{Inn}(F_n),  \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \rangle\rangle.$$


We adopt the following convention: $[x, y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.
Remark 1. We have $\alpha_{112}^2 \in \langle \langle \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n \rangle\rangle$ since $[\epsilon_1, \alpha_{112}] = \alpha_{112}^2$.
Remark 2. By Andy Putman's computation, we actually have $\alpha_{112} = [\lambda_{12}, \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2]$, thus assertion $(ii)$ is true.
Notation match. $L_{12} = \lambda_{12}, C_{12} = \alpha_{112}^{-1}$ and $f = \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2$.
In keeping with [3, Definition 2.4], the automorphisms
$\epsilon_i, \rho_{ij}$ and $\lambda_{ij}$ of $F_n$ are defined as follows: for every $i, j, k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $i \notin \{j, k\}$, we set $$\rho_{ij}(a_i) = a_i a_j, \lambda_{ij}(a_i) = a_j a_i, \text{ and }\epsilon_i(a_i) = a_i^{-1}, $$
$$\rho_{ij}(a_k) = \lambda_{ij}(a_k) = \epsilon_i(a_k) = a_k.$$
We shall derive the claim from the next three lemmas.
We will only show the third lemma as the others are well-known.
First, let us observe that since the derived subgroup of $F_n$ is characteristic, every automorphism $\phi$ of $F_n$ induces an automorphism $\overline{\phi}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. The group of the automorphisms of $F_n$ which induces the identity on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is the group $\operatorname{IA}(F_n)$ of the Bachmuth automorphisms of $F_n$. Clearly, $\operatorname{IA}(F_n)$ contains $\operatorname{Inn}(F_n)$. Nielsen showed that $\operatorname{IA}(F_n)$ is normally generated by $\alpha_{112}$ for every $n \ge 2$ [1, Remarks following Proposition I.4.15]. It is also known that $\operatorname{IA}(F_2) = \operatorname{Inn}(F_2)$, see [1, Proposition I.4.5] while the Torelli group $\operatorname{IA}(F_n)/\operatorname{Inn}(F_n)$ is non-trivial and torsion free if $n > 2$ [1, Corollary I.4.12].
Let $i, j, k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $k \neq j$.
Define $\alpha_{ijk} \in \operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$ through
$$
\alpha_{ijk}(a_i) = a_i[a_j, a_k], \quad \alpha_{ijk}(a_l) = a_l \text{ for every } l \neq i.
$$
Although we won't need this fact, it's worth mentioning that Magnus and Nielsen showed that the automorphisms $\alpha_{ijk}$ generate $\operatorname{IA}(F_n)$ [1, Remarks following Proposition I.4.15].

Lemma 1.[1, Proposition I.4.4] Let $n \ge 1$.
The group homomorphism $\phi \mapsto \overline{\phi}$ induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(F_n)/\operatorname{IA}(F_n) \simeq \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We denote by $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}, m\mathbb{Z})$ the kernel of the natural map $$\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}).$$
We denote by $\operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ the subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by the matrices $e_{ij} := \overline{\lambda_{ij}}$.
We denote by $\operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z}, m\mathbb{Z})$ the normal subgroup of $\operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ normally generated by the matrices $e_{ij}^m$.

Lemma 2. [2, Exercise from the 'Relative $K_1$' chapter] Let $n \ge 2$. Then we have $$\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z}).$$


Lemma 3. Let $n \ge 2$. Then the quotient group  $\overline{Q} := \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})/ \langle \langle \overline{\epsilon_1}, \dots, \overline{\epsilon_n} \rangle\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.


Proof. Since both groups are generated by elementary matrices (i.e., the images of the automorphisms $\lambda_{ij}$) and the image of $\overline{\epsilon}_i$ is trivial in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, the group $\overline{Q}$ naturally surjects onto $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. To show there is surjection from $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ onto $\overline{Q}$, write
$$\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes \langle \epsilon_1 \rangle$$ and observe that $[ \epsilon_i, e_{ij}] = e_{ij}^{2}$. We infer that $\langle\langle \overline{\epsilon}_1,\dots,\overline{\epsilon_n} \rangle\rangle$ contains $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{E}_2(\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z})$ (Lemma 2). Hence $\overline{Q}$ is a quotient of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})/\operatorname{E}_n(\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, which completes the proof.

We are now in position to prove the Claim.

Proof of the Claim. Clearly, the group $\overline{Q}$ of Lemma 1 is a quotient of $Q$. To see that $Q$ is a quotient of $\overline{Q}$ iff $(ii)$ holds true, combine Lemma 1 with Lemma 3 and the result of Nielsen asserting that $\operatorname{IA}(F_n) = \langle \langle \alpha_{112} \rangle \rangle$ for every $n \ge 2$.

Question 1. (HJRW) Can the Congruence Subroup Property of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ help prove the [3, Proposition 2.8] mentioned by the OP?
Answer. The ambient knowledge of the CSP encompasses Lemma 2, which certainly helps. That's however insufficient as the CSP has no bearing on Claim.$(ii)$.
Question 2. Can the Gersten Presentation of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ [3, Proposition 2.5] help prove the statement $(ii)$ of the above Claim?
Answer. Yes. This is rather an afterthought inspired by Andy Putman's answer: the relations $\rho_{12}^{\epsilon_1} = \lambda_{12}^{-1}$ and $\rho_{21}^{\epsilon_1} = \rho_{21}^{-1}$ are indeed useful.


[1] R. Lyndon and P. Schupp, "Combinatorial Group Theory", 1977.
[2], B. Magurn, An Algebraic introduction to K-theory", 2002.
[3] D. Kielak, "Outer automorphism groups of free groups: linear and free representations", 2018.

